# WPF Canvas, accept mousewheel events

Tags: wpf, canvas, mousewheel

I have a custom `CanvasControl` which draws a ground plane.  I add a new `Canvas` to the `CanvasControl` itself which is what I draw on. I also setup `MouseWheel` events.

```
Canvas drawingCanvas = new Canvas();
this.Children.Insert(0, drawingCanvas);
MouseWheel += new MouseWheelEventHandler(Groundplane_MouseWheel);
```

A lot of elements get drawn to `drawingCanvas` but are never changed (apart from zoom modifications) which means I want to set `IsHitTestVisible = false` to improve performance (the gain is massive) whilst still accepting `MouseWheel` events on the `CanvasControl` itself.  Unfortunately when I do this I lose my ability to use the `MouseWheel`.  Is there something I'm missing?

```
drawingCanvas.IsHitTestVisible = false;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to get input events directly on the top level Canvas, you would have to set its `Background` property, for example to `Transparent`:

```
Background = Brushes.Transparent;
MouseWheel += Groundplane_MouseWheel;
```

Comment: Interesting.. This works but (because my drawingCanvas is translated) panning around is now b0rked. I have actually no idea how to fix this bit?

Comment: Well, you haven't explained much about how your panning works. I guess however, that you could also handle `MouseDown`, `MouseMove` and `MouseUp` events in the CanvasControl, calculate an appropriate panning translation during mouse move, and apply it to `drawingCanvas`.